# Remotely Wipe Data from device in android 2.2

Tags: android, device-admin

How to remotely wipe the data from device?

I have already tried the sample code given in Device administration. In that we can locally wipe all the device data and reset the device to factory settings.

Given in below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Now i want the code for wiping the data remotely. i.e if the phone is lost, user can wipe phone data remotely. Can anybody help please

Comment: You mean a factory reset yeah ? the example that you provided has a link to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#wipeData(int) what problems are you facing ?

Comment: @Reno - I am able to wipe data in my phone by calling wipedata(). But the problem is i want to wipe data remotely i.e if the phone is stolen and i want to delete all phone data then i should call the wipedata() action remotely. So i don't know that how to call that action remotely. In device administration document they have written Security applications that do remote wipe. So i want this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for remotely wipe data of device.

I refer this document **Using Google Apps Device Policy**, this application is made by google.

http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=190930

Answer (score 2):

This is a start for you:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RecoverySystem.html#rebootWipeUserData(android.content.Context)
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BRICK

Are you developing this software yourself or are you on the search for existing remote-wipe solutions?

Comment: I am developing this application. I don't want ready remote-wipe solution. So i want to know how to do code for this

Comment: I already have done wipe data locally by device administration action wipeData(). But i want to call this action remotely from webservice or through sms sending.

Comment: Then you would check how to listen for SMS and when the SMS contains your special code, execute the wipeData. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662420/android-sms-content-content-sms-sent for example.

Comment: If im right you are making an app, which when opened authenticates with a server. If the server detects a funny business call wipe data from inside this app. This means that all enterprise data must be stored in a secured location on the device. The only way of accessing this encrypted data should be by authenticating with the server. SmS is not always a cool idea because i can always go in the airplane mode and use wifi to authenticate yeah ?